# Why are some iTunes Store songs marked as CLEAN when no EXPLICIT version exists?

Tags: itunes, id3-tag

I have downloaded a number of items from the iTunes store which are marked as CLEAN.  I understand this is common in tracks (I'm looking at you, rappers!) where an EXPLICIT song has has the swear words removed or bleeped or reversed etc.  However, the tracks I have are the original recordings, and are not clean versions of tracks that were originally explicit:

[image]

What makes iTunes decide to add these flags to certain songs, and what is the point of a CLEAN tag?

In the example given every track is marked as clean, but I have seen it on individual songs also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had a look at differently tagged files.

The responsible ID3-tag is `rtng` (short for `rating`). If set to `1` the song will be marked as `EXPLICIT`, while `2` shows up as `CLEAN`. Every other value leads to no label.

I recommend [Kid3](http://kid3.sourceforge.net/) as a tag editor.

EDIT:
According to [this](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/QuickTime.html) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/mp4v2/wiki/iTunesMetadata#Content_Rating_%28rtng%29), the values should be `2` (CLEAN) and `4` (EXPLICIT). I can't reproduce those, maybe someone copied it wrong...

Answer (score 1):

This is a hypothesis, but I expect it's because those songs have been explicitly (no pun intended) listened to by iTunes staff to make sure there aren't swears or R references. Another possibility is that artists, when submitting content to the Store, have the ability to flag them this way, and often do so even when no explicit version exists.

Comment: Since these are hypotheses, should it be a comment instead?